# Write row from one table into another table for each row in yet another table

Tags: mysql

I have got 3 tables: `table1, table2, table3`

For each row in `table3` I want to take the values from `table2` and `table3` and insert them into `table1`. Do I need a loop for that? There are no keys or anything, just the 3 tables.

The columns in `table2` and `table3` are all present in `table1` (some with different names), but `table1` also has some more columns which should stay empty.

This is how the tables look in detail:

```
table1:
```

manufacturer2 | store | sku | name | title_farbe | manufacturer | meta_description_dynamic1 | title_modelljahr_prefix | title_modelljahr | size_prefix | title_gender

```
table2:
```

manufacturer2 | sku | name | title_farbe | manufacturer

```
table3:
```

store | meta

So the columns are called almost the same, except for `table3.meta` which should become `table1.meta_description_dynamic1`.

Thanks

Comment: Are the columns the same in all three tables?

Comment: I edited my post with the answer, thanks!

Comment: How is the data in `table2` related to the data in `table3`? There are no common columns so how do you know which row corresponds to the other?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: There is no connection between them. I just want to take each row from table2, combine it with each row from table3 and write that to table1. Its mysql 5.7

Comment: I solved it with PHP, that was much easier :D. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) query, where the `SELECT` query is a `JOIN` on row number between `table2` and `table3`. Since there are extra columns in `table1`, you will have to enumerate the columns for each table e.g.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (manufacturer2, sku, name, title_farbe, manufacturer, store, meta_description_dynamic1)    
SELECT manufacturer2, sku, name, title_farbe, manufacturer, store, meta
FROM (SELECT manufacturer2, sku, name, title_farbe, manufacturer,
             @rownum := rownum + 1 AS rownum
      FROM table2
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
      ) t2
JOIN (SELECT store, meta,
             @rownum2 := rownum2 + 1 AS rownum
      FROM table3
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) r
      ) t3 ON t3.rownum = t2.rownum
```

Note that ordering is not guaranteed in a `SELECT` with no `ORDER BY` clause so results may not exactly match. However for your tables you don't really have much choice as there are no common columns and no natural ordering.

Comment: Thanks, but tabel1 has more columns (which should stay empty) than whats coming from table2 and table3. The query results in an error saying just that. So what do you mean by "enumerate"?

Comment: @Arnie in the `INSERT INTO table1 (col1, ..., coln)` you only put the column names in `table1` that you want to insert into. Based on your question it should be the same set of names for each `col1, col2, ..., coln` in the query since `table1`, `table2` and `table3` have the same set of columns (other than `table1` having some extra ones)

Comment: I did, its still telling me that the select returns differnent amounts of values. The first select has 5 columns and the second has only 2. Both selects together return 7 values and I also insert 7 values in table1.

Comment: @Arnie I think I misunderstood, that `table2` and `table3` have the same columns. Is that not the case? If not, can you list the columns in each table?

Comment: I added the columns in my OP. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Arnie I've modified my query (substantially) to create artificial row numbers to join the two tables on. Note that ordering is not guaranteed in a `SELECT` with no `ORDER BY` clause so results may not exactly match, although in the real world they usually do.